# How to fix "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

When I try to sign in to my website from localhost it works just fine. However, when I try doing the same from my production build it doesn't work. I think I know why but I don't know how to fix it. When I try to login from the prod build (hosted on Vercel) it doesn't post to https://fs-dev.vercel.app/api/auth/login but to https://fs-dev.vercel.app/undefined/api/auth/login. I don't know why it adds and `/undefined/` in the prod build. (I'm using Next.js and their API routes). I have checked, that the `baseUrl` is correct, since the prod build is able to GET data but not POST data.

This is my code for post reqs:

fetchData.js

```
export const postData = async (url, post, token) => {
  const res = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api/${url}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(post)
  })
  const data = await res.json()
  return data
}
```

signin.js

```
const res = await postData('auth/login', userData);
```

Comment: Looks like `baseUrl` is undefined. Add a `console.log(baseUrl);` or use your debugger to verify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the env variable BASE_URL was needed client side. To fix this, I added NEXT_PUBLIC_ in front of BASE_URL

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old question but I just had the same problem. The solution is at https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/troubleshooting-orm/help-articles/vercel-caching-issue

```
{
   "scripts": {
       "postinstall": "prisma generate"
   }
}
```

Add this to your **package.json**